# Old anime where a school girl is a reincarnation of a war god and fights monsters/machines

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime I am looking for is one I remember very distantly so pardon me for my lack of details. To start it off there is a school girl with brown hair down to her ears/neck who goes on a school trip. Everything starts off normal but then these monster/machine(?) things jump down and start wreaking havoc. I don’t remember what happens next but I recall that she is the reincarnation(?) of a war god and can fight the monster/machine things and is also very good at planning war tactics.

I can also faintly remember a white haired boy who I think is also a reincarnation(?) of a war god and at the end I think they kiss (they might not I don’t know.)

Answer (score 5):

Could it be *[Nobunagun](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/nobunagun)*?

> Earth is under attack from otherworldly creatures known as Evolutionary Invasion Objects, and only the agents of DOGOO, a government organization, can keep the monsters at bay. Armed with special weapons infused with the souls of distinguished historical figures, these fighters, recruited by an alien who watched its planet be destroyed by the Objects, are humanity’s best chance against the invaders. Teenager Shio Ogura used to be nothing but a loner and a military otaku, until one day she and her class went on a field trip to Taiwan and found themselves smack dab in the middle of an Object attack. To help save a new friend, the girl picks up a gun infused with the famed samurai Nobunaga Oda, thus securing her fate as the newest member of DOGOO, and protector of humanity!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in a blurb from Anime Planet and a trailer so that OP can see the art-style